# Adding a new optional element in wsdl and not generate the client code using cxf throws unmarshall exception

Tags: java, apache, web-services, wsdl, cxf

We have shared web service which is used by multiple clients, i added a new optional element in WSDL for one of the client. When other clients try to access the web service using the existing client code, it breaks and throws an unmarshall exception. It looks for the newly added optional element.

Client code was generated using Apache CXF 2.5.8

Comment: When you say "optional", exactly how are you specifying that it's optional? What does the equivalent JAXB class for the request object look like?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

As per Jax-WS specification, optional elements must be made nillable. In order to avoid the existing client to invoke the web service without any interruption.